# How to perform filter map reduce equivalent in Pyhon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

Let's assume there are two lists like:

```
list1 = ["num", "categ"]
all_names = ["col_num1", "col_num2", "col_num3", "col_categ1", "col_categ2", "col_bol1", "col_bol2", "num_extra_1", "num_extra_2", "categ_extra_1", "categ_extra_2"]
```

I am trying to create a new list by filtering the elements that 1) **not** contain "extra" and 2) contains the elements of `list1`.

For example, Here is I expect to get something like this:

```
l=["col_num1", "col_num2", "col_num3", "col_categ1", "col_categ2"]
```

In Pyspark this can be done using filter, map and reduce, but not sure what is the equivalent in Python? For now, I am doing this in two steps like below, but I think there might be a more straightforward way of doing this.

```
temp_list = [a for a in all_names if "extra" not in a]
print(temp_list)
['col_num1', 'col_num2', 'col_num3', 'col_categ1', 'col_categ2', 'col_bol1', 'col_bol2']

l = [b for b in temp_list for c in list1 if c in b]
print(l)
['col_num1', 'col_num2', 'col_num3', 'col_categ1', 'col_categ2']
```

Comment: You aren't actually doing any reduce operation (or a map for that matter). You are just doing filtering. You already figured out how to do a map/filter, using a *list comprehension*, you just need to combine the filtering predicates! `[a for a in all_nbames if "extra" not in a and any(c in b for c in list1)]` is one way

Comment: @juanpa Shouldn't that be `any(c in a ...)`?

Comment: @wjandrea yep, I was going off of the description, not the code, but I fixed it. but my point was really about the conceptual understanding - list comprehensions *are precisely for mapping/filtering operations in a single step*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the first part right.

Next, you want to include only those elements of `temp_list` that contain *any* of the elements in `list1`.

```
result = [b for b in temp_list if any(c in b for c in list1)]
```

which gives:

```
['col_num1', 'col_num2', 'col_num3', 'col_categ1', 'col_categ2']
```

Now that you understand the two steps involved here, you can combine both these steps in one instead of creating an intermediate list. Since you want both conditions to be true, use a boolean `and`:

```
result = [a for a in all_names 
            if "extra" not in a 
            and any(c in a for c in list1)]
```

---

Note: The nested loop you have in `for b in temp_list for c in list1` isn't quite right here, because you only want to select an item *once*, even if it contains both the elements in `list1`. Consider, for example:

```
list1 = ["num", "categ"]
all_names = ["col_num1", "col_categ1", "col_num2_categ2", "categ_extra_1"]

# your code here
temp_list = [a for a in all_names if "extra" not in a]
l = [b for b in temp_list for c in list1 if c in b]
```

would give a `l` that contains `"col_num2_categ2"` two times, because the condition `if c in b` is true for *two* values of `c` in `list1` when `b = 'col_num2_categ2'`:

```
['col_num1', 'col_categ1', 'col_num2_categ2', 'col_num2_categ2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehension as an alternative:

```
list1 = ["num", "categ"]
all_names = ["col_num1", "col_num2", "col_num3", "col_categ1", "col_categ2", "col_bol1", "col_bol2", "num_extra_1", "num_extra_2", "categ_extra_1", "categ_extra_2"]

result = [a for a in all_names for c in list1 if 'extra' not in a and c in a]

print(result)

# ['col_num1', 'col_num2', 'col_num3', 'col_categ1', 'col_categ2']
```